# leetcode 617. Merge Two Binary Trees why is my solution not working

Tags: merge, tree

```
def mergeTrees(self, t1, t2):
    """
    :type t1: TreeNode
    :type t2: TreeNode
    :rtype: TreeNode
    """
    if t1 is None and t1 is None:
        return None
    val1=t1.val if t1!=None else 0
    val2=t2.val if t2!=None else 0
    val=val1+val2
    newNode=TreeNode(val)
    newNode.left=self.mergeTrees(None if t1 is None else t1.left, None if t2 is None else t2.left)
    newNode.right=self.mergeTrees(None if t1 is None else t1.right, None if t2 is None else t2.right)
    return newNode
```

Your input

[1,3,2,5]
[2,1,3,null,4,null,7]
Your answer

[3,4,5,5]
Expected answer

[3,4,5,5,4,null,7]

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo on this line -> `if t1 is None and t1 is None:`

it should be `if t1 is None and t2 is None:`